# Does a single Observable notify sequentially to all its Observers?

Tags: java, rx-java

I coded an `ObservableList` based on a `PublishSubject`. Everytime a client add an element to this list then the Observers get notified via the `onNext` method on the Subject.

I have coded two sample Observers and subscribed them to the `ObservableList`. I have noticed that the notification is sequential and blocking. So if I have these two observers subscribed then the following happens:

- The observers get notified in the same order as subscribed.
- If an Observer is blocking then the next Observer is only notified when the previous one has ended its execution.

I really don't care id the invocation is sequential but want to understand why the notification is blocking as well and how can I make it not to be blocking.

Here is the code for the `ObservableList`

```
package co.com.subjects.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.functions.Action1;
import rx.subjects.PublishSubject;

public class ObservableList<T>{

    public String nombre;
    protected final List<T> list;
    protected final PublishSubject<T> onAdd;

    public ObservableList(String nombre) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<T>();
        this.onAdd = PublishSubject.create();
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void add(T value) {
        list.add(value);
        onAdd.onNext(value);
    }

    public Observable<T> getObservable() {
        return onAdd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> want to understand why the notification is blocking

The implementation of RxJava assumes that executing the `onNext` method of an Observer is always fast and cheap, so `PublishSubject` just calls all `onNext` methods of its Observers one after the other, without introducing any concurrency.

> as well and how can I make it not to be blocking

Before subscribing your observers, you could insert `.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())` (or a different scheduler, depending on your needs), so that the `onNext` calls are executed on a thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it non blocking by wrapping the observers in an observer which notifies it in an ExecutorService.

Obviously adding a task to another pool is fairly expensive so I would only do this when you know it will take a while.  Also note that unless you are careful, events published this way can get out of order. A simple solution for this is to have an single threaded executor for each listener.